# WordPress Multisite wp-signup.php Redirects

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, redirect, multisite

Since changing to WordPress Multisite, my redirects are no longer working.

Previously, [forbes.catholic.edu.au](https://forbes.catholic.edu.au) redirected to [wf.catholic.edu.au/schools/forbes](https://wf.catholic.edu.au/schools/forbes) (we own both domains).

Here's how it looks in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forbes\.catholic\.edu\.au$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.forbes\.catholic\.edu\.au$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.wf\.catholic\.edu\.au\/schools\/forbes\/" [R=301,L]
```

Now that we're on Multisite, I want [forbes.catholic.edu.au](https://forbes.catholic.edu.au) to redirect to my new site [forbes.wf.catholic.edu.au](https://forbes.wf.catholic.edu.au). I tried changing the bottom line of the above code to reflect this but it didn't work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forbes.catholic.edu.au$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.forbes.catholic.edu.au$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ https://forbes.wf.catholic.edu.au/$1 [R=301,L]
```